# Crashlytics is not deobfuscating my crash-report when obfuscated with a 3rd party obfuscation tool (not proguard, not r8)?

Tags: crashlytics, deobfuscation

I am using a third-party obfuscation tool to obfuscate my Android app.

I am using the Firebase CLI commands to add the resources id file to the app. I have added the generated google-service.json file as instructed in the documentation.

Then I upload my mapping file (in ProGuard format) to Crashlytics via the Firebase CLI command referencing also the resources id file as described in the documentation which is completed successfully.

I do see the crashes in Crashlytics, but they are not being deobfuscated.

Does anyone have an idea why it does not recognize my mapping file? I am wondering if Crashlytics does not realize that the app is obfuscated and therefore does not apply the mapping file. How could I accomplish that?
I would appreciate any ideas how to make this work with a third-party obfuscation tool or how to troubleshoot why it is not working.